# Python Scapy HEX decode

Tags: python, hex, scapy

I'm trying to decode the signal value (SSI) in the wireless management frame from a scapy sniff function. I have searched and tried a few answeres but with no success. Here's what I have so far. Trying to decode the hex string.

**Code:**

```
from scapy.all import *

def packet_handler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) and pkt.type == 0:
        sig = pkt[RadioTap].notdecoded.decode("hex")
        print sig


sniff(iface="wlan0mon", prn=packet_handler)
```

**Packet Sample:**

```
###[ RadioTap dummy ]###
  version   = 0
  pad       = 0
  len       = 36
  present   = TSFT+Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+b14+b29+Ext
  notdecoded= ' \x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf4\x82\xc2\xc6\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10\x02\x99\t\xa0\x00\xb1\x00\x00\x00\xb1\x00'
```

I'm catching the 'notdecoded' field's value and trying to decode it through straight python.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 600, in sniff
    r = prn(p)
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in packet_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for but try `notdecoded.encode('HEX')`.

Comment: I'm trying to get the 'dBm_AntSignal' field in the HEX string decoded to a dBi value which is a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version of scapy; these are being properly decoded in the update (I'm using 2.4.0 dev263).

Update scapy:

```
git clone https://github.com/secdev/scapy
cd scapy
./run_scapy
```

Or

```
git clone https://github.com/secdev/scapy
cd scapy
python setup.py install
```